# How to generate azure storage secret credentials?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

In Kuberentes secret, required format is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azcreds
type: Opaque
stringData: # use `stringData` for raw credential string or `data` for base64 encoded string
  AZ_CLIENT_ID: xxxxx
  AZ_CLIENT_SECRET: xxxxx
  AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxxxx
  AZ_TENANT_ID: xxxxx
```

How do i get these credentials? I have a Storage account, and when I go to Access keys I only see Key and ConnectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, you need to Login to Azure Portal
- Then open Azure Active Directory
- Then Click on App Registrations
- Then Click on your owned application

[image]

Then Click on your application, You will find the credentials as below:

[image]

To find the Client secret you need to Click on App registrations the click on Certificates and Secrets then you will find your Secret as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your secret template seems to refer to Azure AD Application Registrations.

You need to create a new App Registration and assign the required permissions on the storage account (e.g. Blob Storage Contributor)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current